# Stern-Gerlach apparatus, measurement problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

Consider the diagram below:
[image]

It is 3 Stern-Gerlach apparatus along with some 'lenses' (illustrated here by lines).

**Question**

What would the output at A and B be?

**Additional information**

The problem with this is whether the middle part (i.e. the middle Stern-Gerlach apparatus along with the lenses) is performing a measurement. If it is, then we would expect an output at both A and B; if it is not, then an output only at A. My intuition tells me that it is not performing a measurement and therefore we should expect an output only at A.

Can anyone explain whether this reasoning is correct - how should this situation be analyzed?

Comment: My intuition aligns with yours. But QM is not my strong suit... I do hope this question remains open, and will get an authoritative answer.

Comment: It should be measuring because otherwise how are you to tell if the spin is in the x or -x direction?

Comment: @gonenc which direction do you mean by $x$ vertical or horizontal? (once you tell me I will edit the picture to put some axis on it)

Comment: I should have said horizontal direction instead of $x$. The horizontal direction could either be $x$ or $y$ depending on the statement of the problem.

Comment: @gonenc you don't know if the spin is in the $x$ or $-x$ direction. This information could only be got if we blocked one of the paths from the middle SG apparatus. Hence why I am under the impression that no measurement has been made.

Comment: @Joseph: I thought that the solid lines tell you that there is at least a particle going that particular route.

Comment: @gonenc they do (kind of, remember we don't really have particles :) ), Your point being?

Comment: Could you explain the diagram more? What are these "lenses" between SG's 2 & 3? Are the arrows designating $\hat{y}$ vs $\hat{x}$ alignments?

Comment: @KyleKanos: Isn't it some sort of a beam combiner?

Comment: @KyleKanos The lenses are just there to make the two outputs of SG2 go back into one, they don't have to be lenses but could be magnetic fields etc. An up arrow indicates as Titus Petronius has put it in his answer spin-y-up etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}$
Assuming that the lenses are some sort of a beam combiner and the vertical direction is $z$ (for convenience) and the  I did the following:

After the second SG device the upper beam is in the state $\ket {x+}$ and the lower beam is in the $\ket{x-}$. Combining these two with the beam splitter we have the final state

$$\ket \psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (\ket{x+}+\ket{x-}) = \frac{1}{ 2} \big(  \ket+ + \ket- + \ket + - \ket - \big) = \ket+ $$

where $\ket \pm$ denotes the eigenstate of the $S_z$ operator, which means that after the last measurement you have only particles from the upper "exit" as if you have done no measurement in the middle.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think you are entitled to add wave functions like this at a beam combiner

Comment: See [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/lecture-videos/lecture-1/) lecture by Prof. Adams around 51st min he deals with exactly the same problem you asked, though with colours and softness, the problem is the same. Furthermore you can add the wavefunctions like that. This is what the beam combiner suppose to do in the real world.

Comment: Thanks for your link it was very good. I still think that your analysis is wrong, you are saying that a state in of $|-\rangle$ will also come out $|+\rangle$ but surley it will come out $|-\rangle$

Comment: $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}$Nope I don't say that. If it is in $\ket - $ then $\ket \psi = 1/\sqrt2 ( \ket {x+} \mathbf{-} \ket{x-})$, which is just $\ket -$ if you expand it out.

Comment: How are you deciding if you add or subtract the wave functions?

Comment: $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}$Well you always add but if there is a phase term in front of the state you carry it. Notice that in the case of $\ket -$ the state $\ket{x-}$ has a phase $e^{i\pi}=-1$. For the case of $\ket +$ both of the phases were $e^0$ so I dropped them.

Answer (score -2):

We should expect an output in both A and B. This is because (if I understand correctly what your "lenses" do) the first apparatus prepares a pure state spin-y-up, then the second SG produces output in both the positive and negative value for the spin along the x axis (because the two observables do not commute) and the lenses, bringing together the two ensembles produces a mixed state 50% right and 50% left. So if we mesure again the spin along the y axis we'll have output in both A and B (bacause, again, the two observables don't commute with each other).

Comment: yes but since at SG2 you don't actually perform any sort of measurement, there should be no collapse of the wavefunction  and hence it should remain in the state $|\uparrow\rangle$

Comment: A mesurement is performed whenever there is output in the first apparatus. If this is the case then we'll have "particles" that enters in the second SG. I think the two lines joining means that we do not take record of the result of this second experiment, so the result is a mixed state. If you try to put down mathematically what operators acts on the state this should be pretty clear

Comment: Notice that combining them together would make it look like as if you have done no measurement whatsoever.

Comment: I don't think this is true. You know that a mesurement has been done (particles pass the second SG) even if you do not take record of the result (that is, even if you don't select only one of the beams). In a classical case (that is, one in wich observables always commute with each other like colour and softness of a ball or whatever) the result would be as you say. In any case I'm going to watch your video, now, I hope to get more information, thanks